# Deleting SQLite data from ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I'm unable to delete data from `ListView`. I'm using `SQLite` for the first time and I'm not able to detect the error here. I checked other posts but they were talking about the formatting of the query. I don't think that's the problem in this case, or is it?

**LogCat:**

```
07-31 14:33:20.268: E/SQLiteLog(16651): (1) no such column: aasdfghn
07-31 14:33:20.283: E/AndroidRuntime(16651): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-31 14:33:20.283: E/AndroidRuntime(16651): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: aasdfghn (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM Accounts WHERE name = aasdfghn
07-31 14:33:20.283: E/AndroidRuntime(16651):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
07-31 14:33:20.283: E/AndroidRuntime(16651):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:909)
07-31 14:33:20.283: E/AndroidRuntime(16651):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:520)
07-31 14:33:20.283: E/AndroidRuntime(16651):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
07-31 14:33:20.283: E/AndroidRuntime(16651):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
07-31 14:33:20.283: E/AndroidRuntime(16651):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
07-31 14:33:20.283: E/AndroidRuntime(16651):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.delete(SQLiteDatabase.java:1547)
07-31 14:33:20.283: E/AndroidRuntime(16651):    at com.example.dialog.DataBox.deleteItem(DataBox.java:60)
07-31 14:33:20.283: E/AndroidRuntime(16651):    at com.example.dialog.MainActivity$MyAdapter$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:170)
07-31 14:33:20.283: E/AndroidRuntime(16651):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4231)
07-31 14:33:20.283: E/AndroidRuntime(16651):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17537)
07-31 14:33:20.283: E/AndroidRuntime(16651):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-31 14:33:20.283: E/AndroidRuntime(16651):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-31 14:33:20.283: E/AndroidRuntime(16651):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
07-31 14:33:20.283: E/AndroidRuntime(16651):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
07-31 14:33:20.283: E/AndroidRuntime(16651):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-31 14:33:20.283: E/AndroidRuntime(16651):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-31 14:33:20.283: E/AndroidRuntime(16651):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
07-31 14:33:20.283: E/AndroidRuntime(16651):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
07-31 14:33:20.283: E/AndroidRuntime(16651):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Code:**

```
 public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

            public DataBaseHelper(Context cc) {
                super(cc, DATABASE_NAME, null, VERSION);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                db.execSQL(CREATE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Removed", 2000).show();
                onCreate(db);
            }
        }

        public void deleteItem(String nn) throws java.sql.SQLException{
             db.delete(TABLE_NAME , "name = " + nn , null);
        }
```

**MainActivity:**

```
    holder.n.setText(details.get(position).getName());
    // holder.i.setText(details.get(position).getId());
    // String idd= holder.i.getText().toString();

    final String nn = holder.n.getText().toString();
    holder.p.setText(details.get(position).getPassword());
    // final String pp = holder.p.getText().toString();

    // final int id=Integer.parseInt(idd.toString());

    holder.delBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            BOX.open();
            try {
                BOX.deleteItem(nn);
            } catch (SQLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            BOX.close();

        }
    });
```

Comment: Try  db.delete(TABLE_NAME , "name = '" + nn +"'", null); Single quotes are required. Check the value which is return by db.delete() method

Comment: Alright, I get it. It worked. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in the first lines of the exception you are receiving:

```
(1) no such column: aasdfghn
...
no such column: aasdfghn (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM Accounts WHERE name = aasdfghn
```

The name "*aasdfghn*" is taken for a column name by SQLite. The bug comes from the `BOX.deleteItem()` method:

```
public void deleteItem(String nn) throws java.sql.SQLException {
     db.delete(TABLE_NAME , "name = " + nn , null); // quotes are missing around the name.
     // Should be: db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "name='" + nn + "'" ,null);
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. Something similar happened to me yesterday :)

Comment: This happens while dealing with SQLite I suppose. :p

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
public void deleteItem(String nn) throws java.sql.SQLException{
   String whereClause = "name"+"=?";
   String[]whereArgs = new String[] {nn};
   db.delete(TABLE_NAME, whereClause , whereArgs);
}

holder.delBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       BOX.open();
       try {
            BOX.deleteItem(nn);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
       BOX.close();
       notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```